.NET decompile - reasons for diffs
I have a branch of C# code that is 7 years old, and some executables running in production.  I'm trying to confirm that the branch of code I have was used to build the production executables from 7 years ago.
I started by firing up the oldest VS I have access to (VS2017), and getting the code to build.  Now I'm trying to decompile the production code and compare to my locally built.
I'm finding that it's 95% the decompiled code.  It's that last 5% that I'd like to understand.
I'm using dotPeek and there are times when the decompile seems to result in very similar code, but slightly different syntax.  For example:

Occasional methods show up as override vs. virtual
One custom object comparison uses == where the other uses a custom equality method
One uses a terse inline syntax and the other uses a bloated 7-line version that SEEMS the same
One has an explicit (unnecessary) type cast and the other does not
Local variable names are slightly different (dictionary vs. `dictionary1')

Can anyone help me understand what may be causing the decompile to result in slightly different syntax?  Could it be the version of Visual Studio (and dependent systems) used to build the DLL?  Could it be a different version of .NET runtime?  Are there other reasons for variation?

Would it perhaps be easier to compile the source you have, using the same compiler used to build the code seven years ago, then diff the decompiled prod code with a decompiled version of your local build?

Decompilers don't neccessarily spit out the same code as the original source-code.  Reasons might be different language- or framework-versions. The decompiler for instance uses C#11, whereas your code was originally written in C#4. They don't neccesarily spit out valid code. Chances are, the decompiled code isn't even compliable at all. You should never rely on the results of a decompiler in that way.

Having said this there are simply too many reasons, all of which are pure guesses about how JetBrains decided o implement it.

Do you think you could successfully unscramble a cheese omelette back into the set of ingredients that came out of the refrigerator? Some transformations are one way.. Some of the things you think exist in C#, don't actually exist in C#; a foreach is completely rewritten to be a while loop during compilation. How can the decompiler know for sure that the while loop it sees was originally a foreach and not simply that the dev human wrote a while? Have a play with http://sharplab.io

@sharplab.io - My assumption was that if the exact same source code was compiled, and then decompiled (by the same toolset), the decompile results would be the same.  I'm looking for the variables that may cause variance in that chain of steps.

@SimonMᶜKenzie - That's what I'm attempting to do, but unfortunately nobody knows the exact compiler/build steps from seven years ago.  The compiler/visual studio version may be something I could chase down.  Good idea!
